# how i can minimize column width in a table in html?

Tags: html, css

i have a table like this

[image]

but i want the options column to be small like this

[image]

code(im using bootstrap 4):

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead class="table-primary">
                            <tr class="text-center">
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">Nom</th>
                                <th scope="col" colspan="2">Options</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                        <tbody class="table-light">
                        <tr class="text-center">    
                                <th scope="row"><?php echo $donnees[0]; ?></th>
                                <td><?php echo $donnees[1]; ?></td>
                                <td><a href="#"><img src="res\images\edit-icon.svg" height="30x" title="modifier"></a></td>
                                <td><a href="#"><img src="res\images\delete-icon.svg" height="30x" title="supprimer"></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very easy solution would be to set the `width` of your options header to 1%. The width will then be 1% or if the content is bigger, the size of the content. Like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead class="table-primary">
                        <tr class="text-center">
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Nom</th>
                            <th scope="col" colspan="2" width="1%">Options</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    <tbody class="table-light">
                    <tr class="text-center">    
                            <th scope="row"><?php echo $donnees[0]; ?></th>
                            <td><?php echo $donnees[1]; ?></td>
                            <td><a href="#"><img src="res\images\edit-icon.svg" height="30x" title="modifier"></a></td>
                            <td><a href="#"><img src="res\images\delete-icon.svg" height="30x" title="supprimer"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
```